# Runnable Python File Without Python Installed

Tags: bash, python-2.7, exe

I'm coding a Python application. If I convert it into a .exe (.pyw/.py to .exe), will it be runnable on other PC's without python?

Comment: Not directly, but you can package everything along with the `.exe`. See http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/FAQ. You can follow their tutorial to get a basic understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Your best option is probably [cx_Freeze](https://anthony-tuininga.github.io/cx_Freeze/), which will bundle all the needed files into one convenient package (and it's fairly well maintained).